# Text search tool for large source code set with up to date pre-indexing?

Tags: regex, full-text-search, code-search-engine

I'm doing maintenance of a few branches of middle-size C++ project (~15k files for each branch). Very often I have to search all project files for given string or regex. Currently I'm using Total Commander which has all features I want (case-sensitive, regexes, filename masks) but this tool scans all files every time, so it takes a bit too much time.

Do you know any text search tool, which could pre-index whole source tree and allow quick pattern finding? Returning all matching files is a must, preview of found pattern surroundings would be nice. Of course indexes must be updated instantly when something changes.

Visual Studio search is not enough, it only scans source files (not metadata nor custom resources).

Does such tool exists? I'm using Windows XP.

**EDIT**: I've found very usable tool, see my own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found very usable tool here: http://code.google.com/p/ndexer/

I recommend it to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

cscope is able to index c files and to some extent c++ as well.
I personally use the KDE front-end KScope which is user-friendlier than cscope's ui.

apart from that you might want to have a look at [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)

Comment: Windows solution is needed, question edited. Also all files must be searched (also binary-alike), not only source code files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure (I have no experience), but I would give Eclipse CDT a try. It indexes all your sources for fast lookup of symbols, similar to Eclipse JDT (Java tools).

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way to sidestep the problem is to put all the source code on a RAM disk.  By speeding up the file IO in this way, you'll see a big jump in performance without otherwise changing your tool chain.

Comment: Will not necessarily help. All modern OSes cache disk access anyway, so after the first search the stuff will already be in RAM.

Comment: ~500 MB sources per branch - too big to keep a few branches in RAM-disk (WinXP 32bit), too big to copy on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Please see 

http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W1300.testAndDemo
and follow the "search demo" link to the code tree search demo.
This will do exactly what you are asking
for and it is a standard demo component of WHIFF.  You will have
to add Pygments plug ins to pull out strings of interest from
your binary files (or just read the whole file as 'text') -- out-of-the-box
the indexer will ignore files Pygments doesn't recognize.
There is an easy hack to make it "eat everything" -- let me know if you
want more info.

The installation and command line interfaces for searching are described
at 
http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W1300_1000.search.

Comment: Unfortunately, web application is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, the web interface is just a facade.  There are command line interfaces too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Google desktop search, or how about [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) or [clucene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/) (lucene ported to c++) as a general-purpose indexing tool.

Comment: Does google desktop search suppors restricting indexing to selected directory, allows multiple databases, regex searching and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want a webapp necessarily, but try [Open Grok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Indexing Service appears to match all your criteria.